# MINA access message queue

Tags: java, mina

I have an issue where some or all of my NioProcessor threads in MINA are becoming overloaded.  This is because I actually am performance-tuning my application; I do want it taking on as much work as possible and am figuring out how to monitor it so it can reduce workload when it is full.  I was looking through MINA's source code looking for some sort of structure such as a task queue that worker threads poll from because ideally I can monitor that pool and take some action to reduce work when it becomes full.  Does anyone have sufficiently knowledge of MINA's implementation to know if such a structure exists or how to access it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mina-integration-jmx, it's an add-on. With it you can expose mina's internal for monitoring like filters, sessions, ...

See the user-guide [here](http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch16-jmx-support/ch16-jmx-support.html).